# Can I change the security type of a wifi net via registry or group pol?

Tags: windows-7, wifi, wpa, wpa2

I have some Windows 7 machines that are configured to connect to the wireless network here as WPA-Enterprise/TKIP. In order to have them work with 802.11n, we need to move them across to WPA2-Enterprise/AES. Is there any way to do this programmatically e.g. script, reghack or group policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an Active Directory domain, your best bet would be to roll out an SSID with the settings you're looking for to the clients [using Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730674.aspx). (You can use [`netsh`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744889(WS.10).aspx) to do this via script, but if you've got an AD domain Group Policy is much easier...)

Comment: The following line did the trick:
netsh wlan set profileparameter name="MYPROFILENAME" authentication=WPA2 encryption=AES